# Is there a more optimal way to space widgets within a column?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, user-interface, widget

So i'm emulating an old app I have where the UI looks like this [image: Example UI]

Currently i'm focused on creating the UI layout for the purple side bar, I did that by creating a Container with a purple background. Within the container I created a column with multiple children and just used an empty SizedBox to create distance between one widget from another.

[image: Flutter UI]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   title: Text('Sample Text'),
      //   elevation: 5.0,
      // ),
      body: _buildContent(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    // private method
    return Container(
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 80.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 140.0,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 80.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 80.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm quite new to flutter so i'm wondering if there's a better way to structure my layout of the side bar? Also to think in the future, since the name "BagTrack" Is on the same level as "Analytic Overview" Should that just be one giant row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Actual answer

#### Method 1

[@Mahfuzur Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15680379/mahfuzur-rahman) answer is good, but to actually answer your question about other ways. `Flex` widgets (`Column` and `Row` extend the `Flex` widget), have both `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment`, they can be used to align them more easily between different devices/screens sizes.

So maybe grouping your red and purple boxes in a `Column` with `mainAxisSize` set to `MainAxisSize.min`, and aligning the surrounding column with a specific size.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

#### Method 2

Another way, if you would like some widget to occupy some percentage amount of space from it's parent, I suggest you look into [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget, [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget.

#### Method 3

Or even [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) could be a good widget for you, but then I would also look at this [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget to solve the potential [Unbounded Height/Width](https://youtu.be/jckqXR5CrPI) exception.

### Second smaller question

It's entirely up to you to decide about your second question concerning the giant row. I wouldn't do it though. Probably would use a `const SizedBox` or `const EdgeInsets` (for `Padding`) and keep them at the same height this way.

### Just complementing Flutter knowledge

PS: Since you are new to Flutter. As a suggestion for future performance: avoid the `Container` widget as much as you know, there are a lot of simpler widgets like `SizedBox`, `ColoredBox`, `DecoratedBox` and `Padding` that you can use in its place that could be marked as const sometimes and be less expensive.

For understanding `final` and `const`:

- `final` is a variable that cannot be reassigned by accident inside your code. When you instantiate it you give it a value and that's it. (Using `late` changes that a bit but not much);
- `const` is a variable assigned by the compiler, if you are familiar with C it's like `#define` but there is a little difference, every time you say `const EdgeInsets.all(8)` for example, the compiler will detect that and use the same variable, so you don't have to remember a specific constant variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. But using `SizedBox` also wont hurt.

I usually Prefer `ListTile` for each element in the drawer.

```
ListTile(
leading: GestureDetector(
behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
onTap: () {},
child: Container(
  width: 48,
  height: 48,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: const CircleAvatar(),
   ),
  ),
  title: const Text('title'),
  dense: false,
  )
```